# Quarkus access to remote resources

Tags: jms, jndi, quarkus

everyone,
I have an application that we're switching to quarkus.
So far I could do a remote lookup via JNDI to a JMS queue in a weblogic. But it seems that Quarkus does not support JNDI anymore.

So my question is, how can I do the lookup on the remote queue in WLS?
My old code was like that

```
  Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable();
  env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
  env.put("java.naming.provider.url", url);
  InitialContext context = new InitialContext(env);
  ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup(jmsConnectionFactory);
  Destination destination = (Destination) context.lookup(jmsDestination);
  connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

  session = connection.createSession(true, 1);
  sender = session.createProducer(destination);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quarkus indeed does not support JNDI.

JMS can be used via the [Quarkus QPid extension](https://github.com/amqphub/quarkus-qpid-jms/).
You can read the documentation [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/jms) and view a quickstart application [here](https://github.com/amqphub/quarkus-qpid-jms-quickstart).

Comment: Thanks i will check it :-)